# Conditional execution on .bat files

Tags: batch-file, dosbox

I'm stuck with my .bat that doesn't execute correctly if any mistakes please report it

File name - games.bat

```
@echo off
G:

:start
cls
echo DOS Games
echo 1. DOOMS
echo 2. Prince of Persia

set /p choice=Your Choice is

pause

if %choice% == 1 goto 1
if %choice% == 2 goto 2
if %choice% == %choice% goto start

:1
cd PRINCE~1
PRINCE.EXE

exit

:2
cd DOOMS
DOOM.EXE

exit
```

I just want to run the games by selecting their numbers

I'm running the .bat in DOSBOX which may not be compatible with windows bat syntax

Also any other suggestions are ok to me

I'm tierd of writing new config files and shell scripts again and again for many games so I decided to write a .bat code which can run on DOSBOX and load games one by one

Comment: Are you really using DOS or are you using Windows cmd? In DOS there's no `set /p`

Comment: I'm running the .bat file in Dosbox of recent version

Comment: Alternatively I can use mount command but still I stumbled with numbers on 26 drivers can be mounted to dos I have more than 26 games I have to switch games one by one by changing disks and running exes which is cumbersome to me

Comment: Is there a `choice` command?

Comment: Alternatively I can use mount command but still I stumbled with numbers on 26 drivers can be mounted to dos I have more than 26 games I have to switch games one by one by changing disks and running exes which is cumbersome to me
Like

`mount A path/to/game1`
`mount B path/to/game2`
`mount C path/to/game3`
.
.
.
upto 26 games

Comment: choice command not working evn I tried that

Comment: don't edit the question to mark it as solved, just click the check mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [choice command](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Commands#CHOICE) is available for dosbox and probably the only way to achieve what you want:

```
mount G .
G:
:start

rem --- descriptions ---

choice /c12 /s Your Choice is [1-2]: /n 
if errorlevel 2 goto two
if errorlevel 1 goto one
goto start 

:one
cd PRINCE~1
PRINCE.EXE
exit

:two
cd DOOMS
DOOM.EXE
exit
```

You can check the the chosen option with `if errorlevel` but mind that errorlevel works like `equal or bigger than..` and you should start with the bigger numbers first. You can check the result only with `IF ERRORLEVEL` as `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable is not accessible and you cannot use the three letter comparison operators under dosbox.

The other thing I've noticed is that there's no mapping of a device. To have access to your files under dosbox you need to [mount a certain directory as a drive first](https://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#START). Here I've mounted G: as the current directory.(or may be it is mounted in the conf file?)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion !
I will make sure bat file folders and game folders mounted as C & G in my Dosbox config
and switch it in bat file

Comment: Successfully it loads can extend error level till 30; bcz I have 30 games so I can switch them easily

Comment: Here is the video on YouTube that reveals the above code https://youtu.be/uhJRbDSno3M

Comment: @Hackdev17 - you should be able to extend the codes by using letters and digits `choice /cABCD12`  and the first choice will give errorlevel 1 the second 2 and so on. I'm not sure if it is case sensitive and what are all the symbols that can be used though.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my tweaks :

```
@echo off

:start
G:

cls

echo  .:::::         .::::        .:: ::
echo  .::   .::    .::    .::   .::    .::
echo  .::    .:: .::        .::  .::
echo  .::    .:: .::        .::    .::
echo  .::    .:: .::        .::       .::
echo  .::   .::    .::     .::  .::    .::
echo  .:::::         .::::        .:: ::
echo.
echo.
echo     .::::          .:        .::       .:: .::::::::   .:: ::
echo   .:    .::       .: ::      .: .::   .::: .::       .::    .::
echo  .::             .:  .::     .:: .:: . .:: .::        .::
echo  .::            .::   .::    .::  .::  .:: .::::::      .::
echo  .::   .::::   .:::::: .::   .::   .:  .:: .::             .::
echo   .::    .:   .::       .::  .::       .:: .::       .::    .::
echo    .:::::    .::         .:: .::       .:: .::::::::   .:: ::
echo.
echo.

pause

cls

echo List of Games :
echo.
echo 1. Prince of Persia
echo 2. DOOMS
echo.

echo Select the Game [1-2]
choice /c12 /s "::" /n

cls

if errorlevel 2 goto two
if errorlevel 1 goto one

:one
cd PRINCE~1
PRINCE.EXE

:two
cd DOOMS
DOOM.EXE

rem --- without cd.. we cannot switch games bcz each time we enter the game folder ---
cd ..

goto start
```